# dell_smm_hwmon: unable to get SMM Dell signature

Tags: 22.04

I have this message in the systemd log.

```
dell_smm_hwmon: unable to get SMM Dell signature
```

I suppose that temperature sensors are controlled by BIOS, and this message can be ignored.

There is the Integrated Intel Xe graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error happened during boot time on Dell Inc XPS 15 9520, Ubuntu 22.04.

I suspect nvidia-driver-525 is buggy. I downgraded to nvidia-driver-515 and got a fix for my NVIDIA [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile]

Comment: There is the integrated Intel Iris Xe graphics on my laptop.

Comment: This is not the answer.